# Постраничный вывод файлов из папки

Tags: php, html, css

Как сделать навигацию?

Чтобы данный скрипт создавал после 20 выводов новую страницу и так до конца файлов. Конкретно нужно для Вордпресс. Зачем мне это нужно? Страница слишком велика. Или может есть другие варианты, флешка, флейм - что не очень хотелось бы.

```
$dir = opendir("/files/"); //путь к файлам
        while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
            if (($file != ".") && ($file != "..") && ($file != "index.php")) {
                $cat   = "$file"; // строка, подлежащая частичной замене
                $r     = array(
                    "yo",
                    "ye",
                    "ts",
                    "ch",
                    "sh",
                    "shch",
                    "yu",
                    "ya",
                    "a",
                    "b",
                    "v",
                    "g",
                    "d",
                    "e",
                    "j",
                    "z",
                    "i",
                    "y",
                    "k",
                    "l",
                    "m",
                    "n",
                    "o",
                    "p",
                    "r",
                    "s",
                    "t",
                    "u",
                    "f",
                    "e",
                    "_",
                    "h"
                ); // что менять ("a" и "b");
                $r2    = array(
                    "ё",
                    "ё",
                    "ц",
                    "ч",
                    "ш",
                    "щ",
                    "ю",
                    "я",
                    "а",
                    "б",
                    "в",
                    "г",
                    "д",
                    "е",
                    "г",
                    "з",
                    "и",
                    "и",
                    "к",
                    "л",
                    "м",
                    "н",
                    "о",
                    "п",
                    "р",
                    "с",
                    "т",
                    "у",
                    "ф",
                    "Э",
                    " ",
                    "х"
                ); // на что менять ("0" и "1");
                $trans = str_ireplace($r, $r2, $cat);

                echo '<img src="/themes/present/images/PostCategoryIcon.png" WIDTH="50" HEIGHT="50" alt=""><a href="/files/' . $file . '">' .$trans. '</a><br>';

            }
        }

        closedir($dir);
```

Comment: Вам нужен paginator?
Меня сбивает с толку фраза "и так до конца файлов".

Comment: Скрипт выводит ссылки на файлы в папке, допустим их 1000 или 5000, получается очень большая страница. Нужно разбить 5000 файлов на страницы по 20 файлов на одной.

Comment: paginator - хм уже есть над чем подумать...

Comment: Я думаю такое название темы более понятно будет участникам чам **Навигация для php программы**...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще обленились... **[Постраничный вывод файлов из папки](http://www.nulled.cc/threads/159800/)**

З.Ы. И еще внимательно прочесть последний пост, он именно для Вас написан!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  
if ($handle = opendir('./files')) {  
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {  
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {  
            $files[] = $file;  
        }  
    }  
    closedir($handle);  
}  
/* config */  
$COUNT_FILES_ON_PAGE = 7;  
###  
$COUNT_FIELES = count($files);  
$COUNT_PAGES = intval($COUNT_FIELES / $COUNT_FILES_ON_PAGE);  
if(empty($_GET['p']) || $_GET['p'] < 0 || $_GET['p'] > $COUNT_PAGES || !intval($_GET['p']))  
$_GET['p'] = 0;

echo '<h2>Файлов в папке: '.$COUNT_FIELES.'</h2>';  
echo 'Всего страниц: <b>'.($COUNT_PAGES +1).'</b><br>';  
echo 'Файлов на страницу: <b>'.$COUNT_FILES_ON_PAGE.'</b><br>';;  
echo 'Текущая страница: <b>'.($_GET['p']+1).'</b><br>';  
echo '<center>Если закачка не началась вставте ссылку в свой менеджер закачек (Download Master)</center><br>';

for ($i=0; $i<= $COUNT_PAGES;$i++) {  
echo '<a href="?p='.$i.'">['.($i+1).']</a> ';  
}  
echo '<hr>';

$START = $_GET['p'] * $COUNT_FILES_ON_PAGE;  
$END = $START + $COUNT_FILES_ON_PAGE;

for ($i = $START; $i < $END; $i++) {

if(key_exists($i,$files)) {  
if(is_file('./files/'.$files[$i]))

$cat = "$files[$i]";  //строка, подлежащая частичной замене
$r=array("yo","ye","ts","ch","sh","shch","yu","ya","a","b","v","g","d","e","j","z","i","y","k","l","m","n","o","p","r","s","t","u","f","e","_","h","w");           // ??????"a" ?b");
$r2=array("ё","ё","ц","ч","ш","щ","ю","я","а","б","в","г","д","е","г","з","и","и","к","л","м","н","о","п","р","с","т","у","ф","э"," ","х","в");          // ???????"0" ?1");
$trans = str_ireplace($r,$r2,$cat);

echo ' <img src="/gitara/themes/present/images/PostCategoryIcon.png" WIDTH="50" HEIGHT="50" alt=""><a href="/gitara/files/'.$file.'" title="'.$trans.' скачать ноты, табы">Табы: '.$trans.'</a><br>';

if(is_dir('./files/'.$files[$i]))  
echo $files[$i].' - [DIR]<br>';  
}

}

?>
```